# Complex double integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm having trouble calculating following (complex) integral.
$$\int_D z^n dA$$
where $D=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \lvert z \rvert \leq 1 \}$.

I know how to calculate complex (line) integrals and real double integrals but I'm having difficulties combining those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Using polar coordinates the integrand is $$z^n=r^n e^{in \theta} $$ and the area element becomes $$dA=rdrd \theta. $$

The limits of integration should be obvious.

Comment: Ofcourse! Stupid question ...

Comment: @mvcouwen not at all! took me some time to figure it out too :)